# How to find the polygons bordering a feature programmatically with qgis?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2

Is there a way to calculate the neighbors of a polygon with `pyqgis` for every feature? For example, the selected polygons relative to the one in the center:

[image: screenshot of selected polygons]

I found [this solution](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/12/tip-find-neighbor-polygons-in-layer-in.html), but it's a year old and doesn't seem to work with QGis 2.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the given solution, Ujaval Gandhi uses [shapely](http://gispython.org/shapely/manual.html)  to find all neighboring polygons of each of the polygons in a layer (function shapely [object.touches(other)](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.touches)).

In PyQGIS 2.x, this function is available (function PyQGIS `object.touches(other)`)

An example:

[image]

For iterating over the features/geometry and compare polygon by polygon I will use the standard [itertools](http://pythonarticles.com/itertools.html) module in the console:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
import itertools
# with itertools permutations, length of the permutations(2) in this case.
for geom1,geom2 in itertools.permutations(layer.getFeatures(),r=2):
      if geom1.geometry().touches(geom2.geometry()):
            print geom1.attributes(),geom2.attributes()
[3] [1]
[2] [1]
[1] [3]
[1] [2]
# with itertools combinations, length of the combinations(2) in this case.
for geom1,geom2 in itertools.combinations(layer.getFeatures(),r=2):
      if geom1.geometry().touches(geom2.geometry()):
            print geom1.attributes(),geom2.attributes()
            layer.select(geom1.id())
 [3] [1]
 [2] [1]
```

[image]

no neighbours (function `disjoint`):

```
 for geom1,geom2 in itertools.combinations(layer.getFeatures(),r=2):
      if geom1.geometry().disjoint(geom2.geometry()):
      print geom1.attributes(),geom2.attributes()
 [4] [3]
 [4] [2]
 [4] [1]
 [3] [2]
```

And the intersections:

```
for geom1,geom2 in itertools.combinations(layer.getFeatures(),r=2):
    if geom1.geometry().intersects(geom2.geometry()):
          print geom1.attributes(),geom2.attributes()
[3] [1]
[2] [1]
```

[image]